# document.getElementById error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a problem using document.getElementbyId. It doesn't show "test" when I open the html file in my browser and I get an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment. I have tried putting the script tag in various places, but it doesn't work.

```js
document.getElementById("demo") = "test";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

I would appreciate any kind of help! Thanks!

Comment: The error is pretty clear: the left-hand side of the `=` expression is something that makes no sense. If you're trying to update the content, you need to set the `.innerHTML` property of the element.

Comment: Function getElementById() returns an element, does not set a value, this is why you are getting the error.

Comment: What do you _want_ to happen? The other comments will tell you what is wrong, but what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: As he tells in the question, he wants to set the text of tje element with id demo. As @Pointy said, he needs to set the inner text property: (from the top of my head, not sure of the syntax) document.getElementById(“demo”).innerHtml = “test”;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementById` returns an element. If you need to set the text, you could set the [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) of that element, e.g:

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerText = "test";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly assign the string to change the content of the html element.
Refer below the code:--

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="demo">Hello</p>
  <script>
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hey";
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```